# How to target next() in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this `HTML`:

```
  <h3 class="toggle_div">
        <i class="left-image switch-icon"></i>
  </h3>
```

I want to change classnames when I click on the `div`. In this case, *left-image* should change to a classname *right-image*.

This is the `jQuery` I have:

```
$('.toggle-div').click(function(){
     $(this).siblings().next('.switch-icon').toggleClass("left-image right-image");
});
```

I tried this, because the code beneath only works if I put the `<i>` element underneath the div element I want to use to toggle. So it seems like I can't get the classname of the  element that is within the div element.

```
$('.toggle-div').click(function(){
     $(this).next('.switch-icon').toggleClass("left-image right-image");
});
```

What can I use to make it work?

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/f72FY/69/

Comment: your class name is wrong in javascript. it's toggle_div not toggle-div

Comment: `.switch-icon` is not sibling of `toggle_div` - it's a child element.   `$(this).find(".switch-icon")`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f72FY/70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to find `.switch-icon` within the element which is clicked

```js
    $('.toggle_div').click(function(){
         $(this).find('.switch-icon').toggleClass("left-image right-image");
    });
```

```css
.left-image
{
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/euD9p.png');
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   
}
.right-image
{
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzs9m.png');
     width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <h3 class="toggle_div">
      Clicking on this text should toggle
        <div class="left-image switch-icon"></div>
      </h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your class name is wrong in JS. and then you don't need $(this).siblings().next

Just try this

```
$('.toggle_div').click(function(){
     $('.switch-icon').toggleClass("left-image right-image");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it now.

Comment: And in 20 minutes time, OP raises a new question:  which I click one div, it changes all switch-icons, how do I make it only change one...

Answer (score 1):

You may use .children Or .find with in the method. That should be able to retrieve the full element details based on selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('.toggle_div').click(function(){
                  $('div.switch-icon').toggleClass("left-image right-image");
    });
```